# Why do all of the links to filter 'hot' answers go to filter=day?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I checked this on several tag pages. For instance, on the [hot answers page for the PHP tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/hot?filter=day), the 'all', 'year', 'month', 'week', and 'day' buttons all link to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/hot?filter=day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a bug, its been fixed, thanks for reporting it